# PERL Script To Compare 3 CSV Files & Create a New CSV File

Tags: perl, shell, csv, compare

I'm working to compare 3 csv files and create another csv file with the new output.

**File 1**

```
  Name,Color,Food,Point
  David,Orange,Pasta,12.34
  Raver,Blue,Pizza,13.35
  John,Red,Noodles,14.36
  Armond,Black,Sandwich,15.37
```

**File 2**

> ```
> Name,Task
> David,Success
> Raver,Success
> John,Success
> Armond,Failure
> ```

**File 3**

> ```
> Color,Stock
> Orange,Available
> Blue,Available
> Red,OutOfStock
> Black,Available
> ```

**Output File**

```
Name,Color,Food,Point,Task,Stock
David,Orange,Pasta,12.34,Success,Available
Raver,Blue,Pizza,13.35,Success,Available
John,Red,Noodles,14.36,Success,OutOfStock
Armond,Black,Sandwich,15.37,Failure,Available
```

Kindly help me.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried something here.

**Output**

```
Name,Color,Food,Point,Task,Stock
David,Orange,Pasta,12.34,Success,Available
Raver,Blue,Pizza,13.35,Success,Available
John,Red,Noodles,14.36,Success,OutOfStock
Armond,Black,Sandwich,15.37,Failure,Available
```

This works!

```
#! /ms/dist/perl5/bin/perl5.10
use strict;

my $file1csv = $ARGV[0];
my $file2csv = $ARGV[1];
my $file3csv = $ARGV[2];

open(ff, "<$file1csv");
my @file1_array = <ff>;
close ff;

open(fg, "<$file2csv");
my @file2_array = <fg>;
close fg;

open(f, "<$file3csv");
my @file3_array = <f>;
close f;

open(g, ">Output.csv");
print g "Name,Color,Food,Point,Task,Stock\n";

foreach my $file1_value (@file1_array)
{
    $file1_value =~s/^\s+|\s+$|\s//igs;
    $file1_value = $file1_value . ",";
    print "Processing\n";

    if($file1_value =~m/^([^\,]*)\,([^\,]*)\,([\w\W]*)\,$/is) 
    {
        my $name = $1; chomp($name);
        my $color = $2; chomp($color);
        my $remaining = $3; chomp($remaining);
        # my $point = $4; chomp($point);
        print "Processing for the name :: $name\n";

        my $task;
        foreach my $file2_value (@file2_array)
        {
            $file2_value =~s/^\s+|\s+$|\s//igs;
            $file2_value = $file2_value.",";

            if($file2_value =~m/$name\,([^\,]*)\,/is)
            {
                $task = $1; chomp($task);
            }
        }

        my $stock;
        foreach my $file3_value (@file3_array)
        {
            $file3_value =~s/^\s+|\s+$|\s//igs;
            $file3_value = $file3_value.",";

            if($file3_value =~m/$color\,([^\,]*)\,/is)
            {
                $stock = $1; chomp($stock);
            }
        }

        open(g, ">>Output.csv");
        print g "$name,$color,$remaining,$task,$stock\n";
    }
}
close g;
print "Completed\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use 2 `join`s:

```
join -t, -j 1 file1 file2 | join -t, -1 2 -2 1 -o 1.1,1.2,1.3,1.4,1.5,2.2 - file3
```

**Explanation:**

- `join -t, -j 1 file1 file2`: joins the first two files at field 1.
- `join -t, -1 2 -2 1 ... - file3`: the previous statement represents now the first file (`-`). This is joined with the 3rd file.
- `-o 1.1,1.2,1.3,1.4,1.5,2.2`: The output order as in your example.